While running npm install it stucks at idealTree: sill idealTree buildDeps
I had tried to updating node version and cross checked my network status and its working but unable to run npm install command since it gets stucked at  sill idealTree buildDeps
Im using nextjs14 for my frontend and serving data using rails(7.0.1) api

here is my package.json file if you guys can trace something out from
here.

{
"name": "dmv-practice-test",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"dev": "next dev",
"build": "next build",
"start": "next start",
"lint": "next lint",
"db:generate": "drizzle-kit generate",
"db:migrate": "tsx src/db/migrate.ts",
"test": "jest",
"test:watch": "jest --watch"
},
"dependencies": {
"@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.4",
"@radix-ui/react-accordion": "^1.1.2",
"@radix-ui/react-alert-dialog": "^1.0.5",
"@radix-ui/react-checkbox": "^1.0.4",
"@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.0.5",
"@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.0.2",
"@radix-ui/react-navigation-menu": "^1.1.4",
"@radix-ui/react-progress": "^1.0.3",
"@radix-ui/react-radio-group": "^1.2.0",
"@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
"@radix-ui/react-tabs": "^1.1.0",
"@radix-ui/react-tooltip": "^1.0.7",
"@react-hook/resize-observer": "^1.2.6",
"@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^2.6.2",
"@stripe/stripe-js": "^3.2.0",
"@tanstack/react-query": "^5.17.19",
"@types/better-sqlite3": "^7.6.11",
"@types/js-cookie": "^3.0.6",
"@types/node": "20.3.1",
"@types/react": "^18.2.12",
"@types/react-dom": "^18.2.5",
"axios": "^1.4.0",
"better-sqlite3": "^11.1.2",
"class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
"clsx": "^2.1.0",
"date-fns": "^2.30.0",
"drizzle-orm": "^0.32.0",
"embla-carousel-react": "^8.0.0-rc19",
"eslint": "8.43.0",
"eslint-config-next": "^14.0.4",
"js-cookie": "^3.0.5",
"lucide-react": "^0.307.0",
"next": "^14.0.4",
"next-auth": "^5.0.0-beta.18",
"next-themes": "^0.3.0",
"nextjs-toploader": "^1.6.12",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-dropzone": "^14.2.3",
"react-hook-form": "^7.51.0",
"react-icons": "^4.9.0",
"react-intersection-observer": "^9.5.2",
"react-pdf": "^7.7.1",
"sonner": "^1.4.41",
"stripe": "^14.23.0",
"tailwind-merge": "^2.2.0",
"tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
"ts-node": "^10.9.2",
"tsx": "^4.16.2",
"typescript": "5.1.3",
"uuid": "^9.0.0",
"zod": "^3.22.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@playwright/test": "^1.41.2",
"@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.10",
"@tanstack/eslint-plugin-query": "^5.17.20",
"@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^5.17.19",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
"@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
"@types/uuid": "^9.0.7",
"autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
"drizzle-kit": "^0.23.0",
"jest": "^29.6.1",
"jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.6.1",
"jest-fetch-mock": "^3.0.3",
"postcss": "^8.4.33",
"tailwind-scrollbar": "^3.1.0",
"tailwindcss": "^3.4.1"
}
}

Tried lots of solution, but the issue was from my isp LOL.
As per the isp, Its was network issue.
